# Why are some specific names / items harder to remember

Tags: memory

I will take an example specific to myself to illustrate:

Having a very solid music culture and a quite good one about movies, a few cues usually help me remember the works in question.

Sometimes I am confronted to a name, like a movie name, or a song name and I know that this one, this specific one, I will have a hard time to remember its name. I feel it right away.
And sure enough, this is usually right and I just can't remember the name, no matter if I see it written many times. I know the audio, the visuals, I can feel it, but I don't know the words.

It seems to happen with very specific names and it very rare; it almost feels like 'oh, this word is mapped to a specific black hole in my memory, and I can't register it'; it's not an age thing, it was always like that.

What is interesting is that I know it at the beginning; the question is if I prime myself for forgetting it, or if I know there is some characteristic of it that I can't handle.

So, assuming I'm not unique in this, my question is: what would make some things hard vs. simple to memorize when they seemingly require the same effort to evaluate and remember?